# In DevExpress.XtraGrid Control ,How to set the height of the row to adjust the big text

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

The width of the column is fixed,and I hope that the height of the Row can be adjusted automatically.

PS:
gridView1.OptionsView.RowAutoHeight = true;  does not worked
Thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the solution discussed in the below link.
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A8/auto-height-of-grid-rows-and-text-wordwrap

Comment: Thanks bro,I have finished it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the help from the abrove,I make some summary to show the way to help more who face the same problems:

```
1.RepositoryItemMemoEdit Rme = new RepositoryItemMemoEdit(); 
2.Rme.WordWrap = true;
3.ColValue.ColumnEdit = Rme;(ColValue:DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn)
4.RowAutoHeight = true;
```